# Fade effect for video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm testing a fade out effect for a video. The two videos are equal in length and I tried the following command.

But what I get is a repeat from the beginning of the 1st video every time the effect starts. Specifically it repeats from the beginning instead of having the fade effect at the same time as the 2nd video.

Is there any way I can get the same effect and their timing is the same.

`[0]crop=iw/1.1:ih/1.1,scale=1000:1080,fade=in:st=0:d=3:alpha=1,fade=out:st=6:d=3:alpha=1,loop=999:225,setpts=N/25/TB [ovr];[1]mpdecimate,setpts=N/25/TB[v2];[v2][ovr] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2"`

Comment: I often wonder why people struggle with command-line video solutions when one of the world's finest video editing suites is available ***free*** for personal use. [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/) - Mac, Win & Nix.

Comment: it's a nice solution that doesn't need to be installed. I want to explore it

Comment: Show the full command and the complete log.

Comment: ffmpeg -i input25.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=iw/1.1:ih/1.1,scale=1000:1080,fade=in:st=0:d=3:alpha=1,fade=out:st=6:d=3:alpha=1,loop=999:225:0,setpts=N/25/TB [ovr];[0:v]mpdecimate,setpts=N/25/TB[v2];[v2][ovr] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" @llogan all

Comment: @llogan i can't get it to work well with video. With pictures there is no problem.